# Drush command to run cron won't work in Crontab

Tags: 7, drush, cron, civicrm

I am attempting to run two Drush commands from my crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/2 * * * * drush -r /path -l https://www.domain.com/ cron
*/2 * * * * drush -r /path -l https://www.domain.com/ -u civicron civicrm-api job.execute
```

Both of these commands work when I run them manually on the server, however they do not appear to work through crontab, even though the log shows them running:

```
Apr 17 20:16:01 ip-000000000000 CRON[3736]: (ubuntu) CMD (drush -r /path -l https://www.domain.com/ -u civicron civicrm-api job.execute)
Apr 17 20:16:01 ip-000000000000 CRON[3737]: (ubuntu) CMD (drush -r /path -l https://www.domain.com/ cron)
```

Any suggestion as I cannot see why these would not be running?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue multiple times. I think in all cases cron was running a different version of php.  To fix I ended up having to define my php path in my drush call:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/myuser/bin/drush elysia-cron run --root=/home/mysite/public_html --uri=www.mysite.com
```

Also, another thing that helped me debug the issue is by adding a log path `> path/to/file.log` like this and then looking at the exact error:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/myuser/bin/drush elysia-cron run --root=/home/mysite/public_html --uri=www.mysite.com > /home/mysite/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: I have also been caught by this, all I needed was the path to Drush, I did not have to worry about PHP - I just used 'which drush' for the user the crontab was set up for and substituted this path in the script.  You can check it by creating a simple script that does a drush @your_alias status and redirect that to a log.  Add it to cron to run every 5 mins and you can check all is OK.  Just delete this task after you are happy